# JPQL @query with relation table to json

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, jpql

I am using `@Query` to create a JPQL query to get the list of relations data to JSON

```
package thymeleaf.test.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import thymeleaf.test.model.Student;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface StudentRepo extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer> {

    @Query("select s,t.teachName FROM Student s JOIN s.teacher t WHERE s.teacher.teachName= t.teachName")
    List<Student> findAll() ;
}
```

I got the following result:

```
[
 [
   {
     "stuId": 1,
     "stuName": "Pawarut klai-armon                      ",
     "stuAge": 21
   },
   "sgkyrtgefewd                            "
 ]
]
```

I want this query to return this instead:

```
[
 {
   "stuId": 1,
   "stuName": "Pawarut klai-armon                      ",
   "stuAge": 21
   "teachName": "sgkyrtgefewd                            "
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly name fields you ant to get, like this:

```
select s.stuId, s.stuName, s.stuAge, t.teachName FROM Student s JOIN s.teacher t WHERE s.teacher.teachName= t.teachName
```

If you need to have your fields named, than you need to define DTO object like this:

```
class StuInfoWithTeacherName {
  private long id;
  private String stuName;
  private int stuAge;
  private String teacherName;
  public StuInfoWithTeacherName(id, stuName, stuAge, teacherName){
    //omitted
  }
}
```

Than call query like

```
select new StuInfoWithTeacherName(s.stuId, s.stuName, s.stuAge, t.teachName) FROM Student s JOIN s.teacher t WHERE s.teacher.teachName= t.teachName
```

Comment: thkq for your reply

now i got this result 

`[
 [
   1,
   "Pawarut klai-armon                      ",
   21,
   "sgkyrtgefewd                            "
 ]
]`

can i've field name ?